# Multiprocessing transision takes ~25 seconds.. why?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm  using multiprocessing in my Python scraping program for speed  optimization. However this program takes 30sec to run, so I took a look  "under the hood" and found that the actual processes only takes 4.5 sec.  So the transistion from 1 core to 5 cores takes 25 sec?

```
mp_start_time = time.time()
with mp.Pool() as pool:
    output = pool.map(
        self.parallel_process,
        [(
           link, 
           question, 
           25,
           crawler.webcrawler, 
           self.translator, 
        ) for link in links]
    )
print('Multiprocesses time:', time.time() - mp_start_time)
```

Multiprocess function

```
def parallel_process(self, inputs):
    # Inputs: Must be a dict of all inputs cuz multiprocessing only allows one input
    mli_start_time = time.time()
    # Variables
    link = inputs[0]
    question = inputs[1]
    n_sentences = inputs[2]

    # Modules
    webcrawler = inputs[3]
    translator = inputs[4]
    question_answering = inputs[5]
    print('ml init time',time.time() - mli_start_time)

    # Crawl the website
    # Question is used to rank the sentences
    wc_start_time = time.time()
    webdata = webcrawler(link, question, n_sentences)
    print('crawler time:', time.time() - wc_start_time)

    # Translate into English so our ML engine understands the text
    # Automatically detect language and translates into english
    webdata_english = translator.translate(webdata, dest='en').text


    return webdata_english
```

Is that actaully the case or does something else happen, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Multiprocessing has big communication cost but it seems to be unlikely to be this big. Can you try to swap multiprocessing with threading and make comparison? Threading is more suitable for IO-bound operations like http requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't solve this problem, but the reason was probably that on of the arguments I passed was HUGE... the argument was a ML prediction class. So I ended up just doing it linear with a standard for loop.